# After android system update (Oxygen OS 9.0.3) Google can't reached via hotspot

Tags: oneplus-3

After the system update for Oxygen OS 9.0.3, my OnePlus 3 hotspot has weird problem.

If enable hotspot on my phone and use laptop to browse google.com,
the url is not loading.

If I use a VPN in my laptop and use the same hotspot, everything is fine (so it's not problem in browser/browser plugins).
If I directly use phone to reach google.com, no problem there too (so it's not ISP blocking).

So url filter is happening only in my phone when I use hotspot.

Could someone help me to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0):

After another update today (OS 9.0.4) the problem got fixed!
But still it would be good to know what screw up has happened in the last update.